# Git commit --verbose in Fugitive

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

Is there a way to make `:Gcommit` from Fugitive Vim plugin verbose by default (`git commit --verbose`)?

I've tried the following without luck:

`command! -nargs=* Gcommit Gcommit --verbose <args>`

Also tried creating a `commit` alias in `gitconfig`, although aliases there don't seem to work with existent git commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [issues 126](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/126) of [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/) mentions:

> Since `git commit` doesn't support default options, neither does `:Gcommit`.
>   But you can create the equivalent of an alias:

```
command -bar -bang -nargs=* Gci :Gcommit<bang> -v <args>
```

> With some `autocmd` trickery, you could remap <kbd>C</kbd> as well.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but in your gitconfig file if you add these two lines it'll do the trick:

```
[commit]
    verbose = true
```